# False Positives in Real Time Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, real-time

I am doing a sliding window binary classification. I have time series data and I am running a time window over this data and let a classifier produce a decision probability. Based on this probability, I decide whether I have a positive (p > 0.5) or negative (p <= 0.5).

This classifier performs great in static case, i.e. when it is fed part of the signal that exactly contains the pattern I am looking for, it decides correctly with > 80 % F1-score. However, when I move to the real-time scenario, I produce lots of false positives due to the fact that there are lots of analysis windows being fed to the classifier.

My aim is to localize a pattern in the real-time signal, i.e. know exactly the time interval where the pattern is and make a correct decision. What is a good approach to aggregate real-time classifier results to locate the exact location of the pattern in the signal and also eliminate large number of false-positives that do not normally occur when dataset is balanced in static case?

I hope I could explain my problem clearly. Thank you in advance.